# I want to send a mail with xml layout as attachment in android application

Tags: android-layout

I need some help. I want to send mail when button is clicked with xml layout(the UI design in my application) as attachment

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent to Open the Gmail App and Send your Email. Just get the Text from your XML Layout and then send the Text to the person. Just write this Code on your Button Click Listener:

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            String aEmailList[] = { getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.email_address) };
            String aEmailCCList[] = { getResources().getString(
                    R.string.email_address_cc) };
            String aEmailBCCList[] = { getResources().getString(
                    R.string.email_address_bcc) };

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.email_subject));

            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.email_message));

            startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Hope it helps. Thanks. :)